# How can a joint extend or flex?

Tags: human-anatomy, anatomy, bone, joints

The idea of a joint flexing or extending doesn't make sense to me, I can see how a leg or an arm might extend or flex but how does a joint extend or flex ?

"The hip joint is most stable when it is extended and the ligaments are taut."

Does that mean in the state that is most right in this picture ?[image]

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking, the picture you show is that of the hip joint extending and flexing.

Comment: Which is why I specify the “figure/state which is most right”

Comment: That doesn't help, lets start with whether you mean right as opposed to left or right as in correct?

Answer (score 2):

#### Short Answer

The words extension and flexion actually mean to increase or decrease the angle of a joint, respectively. In other words, the terms are directly related to the joints themselves. Bones can only move relative to each other at joints, so when the angle between two bones increases or decreases, that action is occurring at the joint. In other words, the joint acts as a [vertex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(geometry)) of the angle of movement.

[image]   [image]

#### Long answer

In general, one should think of **extension** as "**increasing the angle of a joint**" and **flexion** as "**decreasing the angle of a joint**" (see [here](https://www.med.umich.edu/lrc/Hypermuscle/Hyper.html#foot), [here](http://droualb.faculty.mjc.edu/Course%20Materials/Elementary%20Anatomy%20and%20Physiology%2050/Lecture%20outlines/muscle_anatomy.htm), [here](https://www.ttuhsc.edu/som/success/documents/introduction_to_anatomy.pdf), [here](https://www.asu.edu/courses/kin335/documents/Movement%20Terminology.pdf), [here](http://www.stolaf.edu/depts/dance/faculty/anthony/courses/Modern-Dance-Language.htm), [here](http://www.mhhe.com/biosci/abio/glossary.mhtml) or [here](http://www.fundamentalsofanatomy.com/pdf/ch08_glossary.pdf) for reference). From Saladin's 2015 Anatomy textbook$^1$:

> **Flexion** = a joint movement that , in most cases, decreases the angle between two bones.

Put [differently](http://teachmeanatomy.info/the-basics/anatomical-terminology/terms-of-movement/),

> **Flexion** refers to a movement that *decreases the angle between two body parts*.

I think where you are confused is that you do not understand what a *joint* is. A [**joint**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint#Anatomical) is anywhere where two bones *articulate* (or touch). Although [various types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint#Classification) of joints exist, those that readily move well enough to receive movement terms such as flexion/extension are called [**synovial joints**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synovial_joint).

At any given synovial joint, two bones are able to move relative to each other due to a cavity that provides space for movement -- the *synovial cavity*. Put differently, bones (which are solid, unbending objects) move relative to each other during our body movements, and this relative movement occurs at *joints*.

**Using your example of arms and legs:**

When your arm flexes/extends, what's happening is that the head of your humerus is moving inside the glenoid cavity of the scapula. This movement at the "[glenohumeral joint](https://www.ortho.wustl.edu/content/Patient-Care/3127/Services/Shoulder-Elbow/Overview/Shoulder-Arthroscopy-Information/The-anatomy-of-the-shoulder.aspx)" results in the entire arm (humerus and all [distal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_location#Proximal_and_distal) components) either swinging forward or backward  due to the angle of the glenohumeral joint increasing or decreasing (though, actually, other movements are possible as well). The same applies to the hip.

Another example is the "elbow" joint -- which actually consists of 2 joints: the [humeroradial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humeroradial_joint) and [humeroulnar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humeroulnar_joint) joints. Consider when you "flex your arm" as in showing off your bicep. Yes, your lower arm (forearm) moves, but the movement all occurs at the point of the elbow at these two joints. In other words, the elbow joints form the [vertex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(geometry)) of the angle between your upper and lower arm bones. When you "flex" your arm, the angle of these joints decreases. When you return your elbow to being straight (i.e., "extend" your elbow), your are increasing the angle of the humeroradial and humeroulnar joints.

[image]

---

$^1$ Saladin, K. S. 2015. Anatomy & Physiology: The Unity of Form and Function. Seventh ed., McGraw-Hill, New York, NY. 1248pp.